# How to train a GCN on heterodata object in torch-geometric

Tags: python, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I am working on a graph classification task where I need to predict the class (1/0, binary) of tweets based on the features of the tweets and users. I have a HeteroData object that represents the graph structure and contains the following components:

- edge_index: A 2D tensor representing the edges in the graph.
- user_features: A 2D tensor representing the features of user nodes.
- tweet_features: A 2D tensor representing the features of tweet nodes.
- node_type: A dictionary specifying the type of each node (user or tweet).
- tweet: A dictionary containing the y vector, which represents the labels for tweet nodes.

  `

  ## Create HeteroData object

  data = HeteroData()
  data['edge_index'] = edge_index
  data['user_features'] = user_features
  data['tweet_features'] = tweet_features
  data['node_type'] = node_type_mapping `

  `HeteroData( edge_index=[2, 2758], user_features=[2128, 8], tweet_features=[2758, 5], node_type={ user=[2128], tweet=[2758] }, user={}, tweet={ y=[2758] } )`

The challenge I'm facing is that the user nodes do not have labels (Y vector). However, I would like to leverage the graph structure and use a Graph Convolutional Network (GCN) implemented with torch geometric to predict the class of tweets.

I'm seeking guidance on how to approach this problem. Specifically, I would like to know:

- How can I incorporate both tweet and user features in the GCN model?
- How can I handle the absence of labels for user nodes during training?
- How should I structure my data and preprocess it to use torch geometric and GCN?